# Ninject, Bind should be .InRequestScope() OR .InSingletonScope()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject-2

I have Below code One is bindable to my User Repository and another for Cache. What scope should I use for UserRepository and Cache. Should Scope on UserRepository be Singleton?

```
    this.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepositary>().InRequestScope();

    this.Bind<IDistributedCacheService>().To<DistributedCacheService>().InSingletonScope();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually the repositories are bound inrequestscope because that generally defines the unit of work or database transaction size.

Update: Here is a bit more information on managing critical resources using ninject. I ran into this while binding my repos inrequestscope.

http://bobcravens.com/2010/11/using-ninject-to-manage-critical-resources/ [[Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160614014634/http://bobcravens.com/2010/11/using-ninject-to-manage-critical-resources/)]

Bob

Comment: Fixed the link.